# Python: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'type' and 'type'. Model.fit() doesn't work

Tags: python, pandas, model

I have a problem when trying to plot partial dependence plots in Python. I used the Random Forest Classifier to create a model:

```
model = RandomForestClassifier()
model.fit(X,y)
```

After which I want to plot the partial dependence on a few features in the model. I tried to do so by running the following code

```
# PDP plot for most important feature of the model
from sklearn.inspection import plot_partial_dependence
disp1 = plot_partial_dependence(model.fit(X, y), X,
                                [8, 11,  12], target = int)
```

However, here I get the error: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'type' and 'type' How can I get the partial dependence plots to run?

X (pandas.dataframe): DataFrame of 16 columns and 94.347 rows.

```
Location                    int64
Complex                     int64
OR                          int64
Surgery                     int64
Operating region            int64
Urgency                     int64
Specialism                  int64
Surgeon                     int64
Size of surgical team       int64
Gender head surgeon         int64
Gender patient              int64
Age                         int64
BMI                         object
Weekday (Sunday =1)         int64
Time of Day                 int64
Expected Operating Time     int64
dtype: object
```

Y (pandas.series): int64, 1 column and 94.347 rows

Comment: Column 12 `BMI` is object type. This may explain it as it perhaps should be a float. Please show an example of your dataframe.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.